# Loading multiple tab delimited files in R

Tags: r

I found some information on how to load multiple files csv files into R.  I am trying modify their code to work with files that are tab separated.  This is the code that

```
#list of files
files <- list.files(currentFilePath)

for(filename in files){
  print(filename)
}

allFiles.list <- lapply(files, read.csv)
```

This code works but treats does not recognize that the data is tab separated.  I have seen examples on using read.table however, this is with a single file. I don't see how I can do it using the lapply approach above with multiple files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add arguments to `FUN` using the `...` argument of `lapply`, e.g.

```
allFiles.list <- lapply(files, read.table, sep = '\t')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I did not realize you could pass parameters to a function in lapply.